# How to combine .NET RIA Services with MVVM in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

The .NET RIA Services are described as an n-tier framework for Silverlight. I have been wondering what the relation is between this framework and the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. Are they in conflict or can you see the potential for synergic combination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET RIA Services and MVVM are synergistic, and aren't in conflict.

For example, if I write a Catalog domain service that exposes Products and Categories on the server, and correspondingly have a Catalog domain context on the client... then the following are options to use depending on the scenario:

1. Write a view model that wraps the Catalog domain context and exposes properties that hand out subsets of data that has been loaded into the Products and Categories lists. And expose operations that turn around and invoke methods on Catalog.
2. Expose a Catalog out of the view model. Often this is perfect for read-only scenarios.

In either case your view model can take care of initializing the Catalog and customizing its creation, setup etc.

Hope that helps get you started in thinking how these might be effectively combined.

We'll definitely be showing some of this working in future samples we put out.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I thought if I don't think about UoW or Repository it will be somewhat awful.

Answer (score 1):

BTW - Shawn Wildermuth has a nice succinct [Silverlight MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx) in the March 2009 issue of MSDN Magazine

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing this, although I don't think this article is so succint and also it does not touch on .NET RIA Services. Well, obviously it hit the 'press' before MIX09.

Comment: Well - I personally found it succinct enough to read on the 30 minute commute into work...but there you go - just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/04/07/using-model-view-viewmodel-with-silverlight.aspx for an example.

Comment: @Maurice With all due respect, I don't see any reference to .NER RIA Services in this blog entry which is otherwise a pretty good and informative one.

Comment: Very true, I will do another blog post covering that. For now just think as the RIA entiry as the Model in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn Wildermuth's example combining RIA Services and MVVM:

http://wildermuth.com/2010/04/16/Updated_RIA_Services_MVVM_Example

Also, the PRISM download on codeplex has docs on this, and includes quickstarts and reference implementations for MVVM and RIA Services.

Comment: Hi Kamran, the blog of wildermuth sounds promising. I have also checked out the PRISM documentation, but couldn't find RIA Services to be mentioned in any MVVM example.  Could you send me the link please? Since I will be using PRISM in my project that would be too good to be true, if I found PRISM supported RIA Services.. Thanks

Comment: The PRISM install comes with a project called MVVM RI MVVM RI code uses both MVVM and RIA Services, as well as other helpful PRISM features. Also, its inlcudes PRism$ compiled HTML help file that describes the implementation. Just make sure you read the PRISM4 readme file so that you install PRISM, the help files, quickstarts and reference implementations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask Jonas Follesoe. He seems to be interested in MVVM in SL.

http://jonas.follesoe.no/

Comment: I will although I know that he is on Stackoverflow.